# Chrome extension and selectionText. How does one create a tab and update the same tab repeatidly

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[[image]google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension)

I´m having trouble with an extension I´m trying to build.

The thing is that I want to allow a user to highlight a word in some tab and get a translation of that word in another window by calling a Translator web page.

The part I have so far and works, is roughly as follows:

I created a context menu item which user selects to get the translation, calling a translate function.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Translate',
    contexts: [context],
    onclick: translate
});
```

In the translate function I create window and send over the selected word.

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url: 'http://www.TranslatingPage.com/index.asp?Translateword=' + info.selectionText
});
```

The question is: How do I update the newly created window? e.g. If I want to translate another word.

Do I fetch all windows or tabs and check if the part of the url holds the value

```
'http://www.TranslateExamplePage.com/index.asp?Translateword='
```

or do i update `LastFocused` tab?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.
Best regards 
Hal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `tabId` of the tab in the new window you created for easy access.

[`chrome.windows.create()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create) passes a [`Window`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#type-Window) object to the callback function. Among other things, this object contains an array of the tabs in it. Since you have just created this window, it will only have one tab. So:

```
var theTab;
chrome.windows.create({ url: 'http://www.TranslatingPage.com/index.asp?Translateword=' + info.selectionText }, function(window) {
    theTab = window.tabs[0]
});
```

When you want to modify this tab again, use [`chrome.tabs.update()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update):

```
chrome.tabs.update(theTab, { url: 'http://www.TranslatingPage.com/index.asp?Translateword=' + info.selectionText });
```